# I am getting the error "Suppress cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am getting the error "Suppress cannot be resolved to a type", where Suppress is a custom annotation.

I have been reading up here, and think I have checked most (if not all) of the posts here regarding this issue, but nothing has helped so far.

During my troubleshooting I have:

* Cleaned and rebuilt my project

* Refreshed and rebuilt my project

* Deleted my project from the workspace and re-imported it

And I still get the error.

Any ideas as to what I am missing?

TIA for any and all suggestions (and no laughing, please.)

Regards,

Steve O'Sullivan

Comment: It's going to be hard for anyone to help without seeing the code, at least snippets of it. Obviously the type Supress isn't visible to the class you're trying to use it in, but you haven't given any details to go on.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this error up by putting a space between supress and warning

```
@Supress Warning
```

check there are no spaces

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project and select 'add support library...' from android tools.
That's how I resolve the problem. Have a try.

Comment: I might be reading the question wrong, but I don't think he means the support Library.